# Divide et conquer algorithm with unordered vector in C++ with computation complexity O (log n)

Tags: c++, algorithm

Given a company's stock market listings stored in a V vector of n integers corresponding to n consecutive days, find in time O(log⁡ n) the first index i such that V[i] < V[i+1]
Assume the average company growing over the time frame considered (so an instance of the index to be searched always exists)
Calculate the complexity of the solution and provide an implementation to the computer

To solve this problem I tried to use the binary search technique but I can not find the right parameters to be able to use it, being the vector not ordered

By giving an example with a vector of 10 elements:

V [400, 200, 200, 300, 100, 100, 300, 200, 500, 500]

The solution values in these cases are:

200 and 300
being the first index with less content than the next index

---

### EDIT

I write the explanation of the average growing company. Practically it is when the stock market quotes considering a time frame for example of 10 days, you have that the stock market listing of the first day is less than the stock market listing of the last day (as an example)

Comment: if the container is not sorted you cannot do a binary search, you cannot find one element among `N` others in less than `O(N)` unless you have additional information (sorting takes `O(n log n)` or better, but also not better than `O(N)`)

Comment: In fact, if the container is not sorted to begin with then you cannot solve that in O(log N).

Comment: As presented, the problem does not have a logarithmic solution. Either the statement is incomplete, or the requirement is unrealistic

Comment: I can't understand this sentence: *Assume the average company growing over the time frame considered*. It might be the key for defining an algorithm, as we need some information on the data to get a solution

Comment: It is possible to find *some* index `i` such that `V[i] < V[i+1]` in O(log n), but not necessarily the first one.

Answer (score 2):

### I am almost certain this is impossible.

Consider the array `[12,11,10,9,8,7,6,0,4,3,2,1]`. That is, an array that counts from 1, except for a single entry which is changed to 0. Finding the solution to your question is now equivalent to finding the `0` in this array, and the rest of the array contains no information as to where it would be. Therefore, this is equivalent to finding a value in an unordered list, for which the only solution is to check the whole list, which is `O(n)` (although you can make it `O(sqrt{n})` on a quantum computer using Grover's algorithm).

### In response to your edit

If the last value is guaranteed to be larger than the first, we can find in logarithmic time *some* index in which the value increases with a binary search-based idea. It is still impossible to find the *first* such index. To see this consider my previous array, except with a large value at the end:

`[12,11,10,9,8,7,6,0,4,3,2,1,100]`

This array has the property that the last value is larger than the first, but to solve the question we would still need to find the 0, which still requires `O(n)` time.